# how to get all reviews of new products on home page

Tags: magento, product, review

I need to show new products on home page with all reviews. I got new products by adding new product widget on home page cms. Can anybody suggest me how to get reviews of these products by editing new product widget file?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout Alan Storms post about extending Magento's widgets it won't directly help you but give you some insight on how to add such functionality to the widget you're using: http://alanstorm.com/widgets_at_magento_imagine_unconference